# Azure Durable Function IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime Returning Same Date Each Time

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

I am invoking IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime in my Azure Durable Function.

```
    var nextRun = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(1);
    await context.CreateTimer(nextRun, CancellationToken.None);
    context.ContinueAsNew(context.NewGuid().ToString());
```

When I look in the logs, I am seeing this message from the task hub (FYI - today's date is 2023-09-27):

```
Function 'RunOrchestrator (Orchestrator)' was resumed by a timer scheduled for '2023-09-15T22:59:43.3915526Z'. IsReplay: False. State: TimerExpired.
```

The date is the same with each invocation. Where does the context get this date? I have deleted the task hub but that didn't resolve the issue.

This same code is deployed in other environments and works fine. How do I resolve a stuck CurrentUtcDateTime?

I am trying to have the durable function sleep for one minute, then resume.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the value from the latest history entry's timestamp in the history table at that point of the replay. Did you delete the tables in Storage? And the queues too?

Comment: I deleted the entire task hub.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the task hub, the function eventually started working again. Not something I would normally do, and definitely not in production.